# Pardot email template campaignMemberId

Tags: campaign, campaign-member, pardot

I am doing some investigation on if it is possible to access CampaignMemberId in an Email template. I have access to all contact information, but I can't find the CampaignMemberId.

Do anyone know if it is possible to access it when sending an email. I want to send it as a URL parameter.

Best regards, 
Christian.

Comment: `CampaignMemberId` is not a valid `WhoId`. `CampaignId` would be a valid `WhatId` and as such, I'd expect the `CampaignMemberId` could presumably be referenced from that object if were used in the Email template. The only issue I see would be that I believe the `CampaignMember` is a look-up to `Contact`, so I'm not entirely certain how the MemberId is associated with it. I'd need to refer to the Object Reference to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into this and been in contact with Pardot support. 
It is not possible to get fields from CampaignMember on the Prospect in Pardot.

The Pardot structure is that a Prospect is equal to a contact and since a the campaignMember is a child to the contact you cannot get fields from the campaginMember to the Contact unless you add a look-up to the campaignMember and then that would only work for that campaignMember and it would not be a general solution.

It is a shame that Pardot does not recognises the campaignMember object since it holds a lot of the important data for a contact in relation to a campaign.